# How to identify which php file a plugin is using on page load?

Tags: php, plugin-development, customization, debug

I need to make some custom adjustments to a 3rd party plugin. My plan is to use PHPstorm and xdebug to dive into the plugin as it loads/operates on a product page so I can find out how it works and make the appropriate changes. The only problem is I don't know how to identify which file to set breakpoints on. Is there a good way to do this? Are there any clues I can glean by inspecting a page via chrome/firefox dev tools?

The specific plugin I'm trying to look at is [Rightpress's Dynamic Pricing and Discounts](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279) and I want to debug it as it loads on a product page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a real dev, but which helps me in some cases: "Query Monitor".
After all, I think you have to start searching backward, step by step and dive into each function.